# Ajax call PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to call a php file from js. I do not have experience with ajax so i don't really know how to use it properly. I use this function :

```
function start(cod){
    var result =0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CheckDetails.php",
        datatype: "html",
        async: false,
        data: {cod: cod},
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And the PHP file :

```
<?php

check($_POST['cod']);

function check($cod)
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $dbhandle = 0;
    try {
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, 'db') ;
    } catch (Exception $e ) {
        echo "Service unavailable";
        exit;
    }
    $name = '';
    $date = '';
    $hour = '';

    $result = 0;
    $codeResult = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT name, date, hour FROM records WHERE cod = '$cod'");
    if (!$codeResult) {
        echo('Database error: ' . mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    } else
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($codeResult)) {
            $name = $row{"name"};
            $date = $row{"date"};
            $hour = $row{"hour"};
            $result = 1;
        }
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

But it seems it doesnt work. I dont really know where is the problem.

Comment: Did you check in the browser console if the AJAX is working and you're getting the response from server?

Comment: I don't know where exactly i should look for in dev tools.

Comment: Look `Networks` tab in Dev tools. You can inspect network requests there.

Comment: You don't output anything in PHP. You should print or echo the return value. That will be the response in the ajax call.

Comment: It tells me that 'CheckDetails.php' has been executed

Comment: @Tushar, this is not an asynchronous call, so it is not that duplicate.

Comment: @trincot, what about that 'echo $result' at the end ?  Is something wrong with it ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. A function with a side-effect :)

Comment: It seems it was a mistake in another part of the code. I'll come back with an answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry to say, but "It seems it doesn't work" is not a good description of an error, Ann. What error messages do you get? Is there any behavior? Is this behavior not correct? Have you set your display_errors to on, so you can receive feedback to know what is happening? All these questions are important if you want to debug something.

Comment: just for your information and future reference PHP has an error log file  too which is on your servers log file dir -- for linux you open a terminal and type -- tail -f  /var/log/apache/error.log --  check for windows on SO or net

Comment: also because you are beginner in ajax you may find the $Post inbuilt function easier to use -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: **NEVER use `async: false`**. it is a terrible practice and you should be seeing deprecation warnings in browser console. It is not difficult to use asynchronous requests

Answer (score 0):

it seems in your DB-query you only read the first result set from your table, and you don't return the results. If I get your intentions right you would have in your last 'else' clause something like:

```
 ...
 else {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($codeResult)) {
      $data[] = array("name" => $row["name"], "date" => $row["date"], "hour" => $row["hour"]);
      }
   }
 ...
```

with having $data declared as array earlier in the code. This way you would have your query results stored in a $data array which you could return as it is or as a json_encoded object.